# Do probability using combination

Tags: probability, combinations

A positive integer from one to six is to be chosen by casting a die. Thus the
elements $c$ of the sample space $C$ are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Suppose $C_1 = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and
$C_2 = \{3,4,5,6\}$. If the probability set function $P$ assigns a probability of $1/ 6$ to each of the elements of $C$, compute $P(C_1), P(C_2), P(C_1 \cap C_2)$, and $P(C_1 \cup C_2)$.

I can compute probability straightforwardly but the question asks me for a specific format. The answer is listed as:

> $${(a)\quad \left.\binom 64\middle/\binom{16}4\right.\\(b)\quad \left.\binom {10}4\middle/\binom{16}4\right.}$$

How do I get this answer using combination technique (I assume the answer is in combinatoric format? Is it a faster way?

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math. I have no idea how to read something like "6 4/16 4". Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @Arthur I don't have access to a direct photo including feature yet so I have the link to the solution format. I am assuming it is a combinatoric format.

Comment: The answers are for a completely different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are wrong. We can compucte $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_1 \cap C_2$, $C_1\cup C_2$ directly and compute its probability directly.

For example $P(C_1)=P(\{ 1,2,3,4\})=\frac23$ and it is clearly different from $\frac{\binom64}{\binom{16}4}\approx 0.00824$

Comment: that is what I thought too. My answers are the same to yours too. Thanks!